# Plotting matrix by columns

Tags: r, matrix, plot

I have a matrix like the following (but with more entries, this is only an example):

```
m<-matrix(c(1,2,-1,0,3,2,1,2,3), nrow=3)
```

i.e.

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    0    1
 [2,]    2    3    2
 [3,]   -1    2    3
```

I would like to plot matrix `m` by columns, as described by the following pic:

[image]

As we can see, at time `0` we have the first column, at time `1` the second one and so on. How can I obtain this result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is something quick and dirty:

```
with(stack(as.data.frame(m)), plot(x = (as.numeric(ind) - 1), y = values, col = "blue", pch = 19))
```

[image]

Comment: Stack is a pretty need little function

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by converting your data to a data frame and by using **tidyr** and **ggplot2**

```
# Your data
m<-matrix(c(1,2,-1,0,3,2,1,2,3), nrow=3)

# Converting to dataframe
df <- data.frame(m)

# Importing libraries
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Converting data to narrow format
df_narrow <- gather(df, "group", "values", 1:3)

# Plotting data
ggplot(df_narrow, aes(group, values)) + geom_point()
```

[image]